# Sessionid is not set to 'application/Cookies' in developer tools

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to implement a login function with Django and React.
Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diB38AvVkHw&ab_channel=Djangoroad
When a post method is sent to login, the sessionid is set only in 'network/cookies'.
Checking the 'application/cookies', only csrfToken is set.

I'm not sure why the sessionid wasn't set to the Cookies.
Is there anything to cause this problem?

here is UserLogin view in django views.py

```
class UserLogin(APIView):
  permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
  authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, )

  def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    assert validate_email(data)
    assert validate_password(data)
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
      user = serializer.check_user(data)
      login(request, user)
      return Response({'user_id': user.user_id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the react function to submit login form.

```
function submitLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    client
      .post("/api/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        setCurrentUser(true);
        setUserId(res.data.user_id);
      });
  }
```